# VST audio input values completely different to those in Matlab

Tags: c++, matlab, audio, vst, juce

Apologies if this sounds like a stupid question, I'm relatively new to VST development. I'm trying to build a plugin using the JUCE framework and I'm currently trying to test it with a sine wave .wav file. When I open the .wav file in Audacity it tells me it's 44100Hz and it's a 32 bit float. When I load this same file into matlab the first three samples are something like 0.00, 0.0443, 0.0884... However, when I put the same file into Ableton and Reaper, and try to step through the code I find the first three samples of the same file are 0.00000000, 0.00012068315, 0.00048156900... I see this when I peak into the memory in VS and look at it in 32 bit floating point view. Why are my sample values so much smaller?

My problem is that I need the audio to have the same sample values as they are in Matlab for my algorithm to work. Obviously there's a conversion happening that I have no control of. Can anyone shed any light on this problem and how I should go about fixing it. It looks like a scaling problem maybe. Ableton is being run in 32-bit mode and my VST is being compiled as 32-bit.

I can also provide more samples if that helps.

Thanks

Comment: Check out the Ableton documentation. As I understand it Ableton is not free. I don't know anything about Reaper. But maybe you can make do with Audacity?

Comment: I think the reason I'm getting the same values in both Reaper and Ableton means it might be the VST SDK or the JUCE framework. However, I haven't tried stepping through Audacity. Great idea.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because Ableton and Reaper were converting the 32 bit audio to 16 bit audio. I was able to check this by loading the sine.wav into Ableton and export it at 16bit. I then loaded the file into Matlab and got the smaller samples like above. My next problem is to figure out a way to convert the 16bit audio to 32bit audio within the VST.

Comment: By the time a buffer of data comes to you in a JUCE AudioProcessor-derived object, the audio graph will already have converted it into either 32-bit float or 64-bit double data that's in the range (-1.0, 1.0) -- see the processBlock() member functions of AudioProcessor.

Answer (score 0):

What you seem to describe is a very low amplitude, thus you will have little values (you could convert your sample values in dB to verify that). Usually an audio signal is ranging between -1 and +1, where the extrema represent the max possible volume in the digital world (aka 0dB).

I believe the dilemma between 16 bits and 32 bits has nothing to do with your issue.

Comment: What I'm doing is converting legacy C code that normally reads in audio files as 32 bit unsigned longs and then converts it to a regular float value. When I compare the float values I get in the legacy code to the float values I get in C++ they are the exact same, but not when I use Ableton and Reaper, so I think this is where the problem lies.